# Find file name in list with extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I need to find the following filename pattern if it exist return true in nodejs
I need the the pattern will return true in case the following name

```
Makefile
makefile
makefile.ext
makefile.abc
```

after the dot it can be any name...what is importent that it start with makefile

I've tried with the following but this give just the ext not the orig file name

```
var patt1 = /\.([0-9a-z]+)(?:[\?#]|$)/i;

var m1 = ("makefile").match(patt1);
alert(m1);
```

Any idea?

Comment: so you can split it using (\n) and filter array with indexOf "makefile"  ?

Comment: Do you need regex? if the first part is always `makefile` couldnt u just `explode()` on the period and check if the first part is `makefile`? E.g. `$fp = explode(".", $fn); if ($fp[0] == "makefile") { do work }` .. ok i was thinking PHP. Same concept however in javascript. E.g. `var fp = fn.split("."); if (fp[0] == "makefile") { do work }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't care about any content after the dot, just split the filename into an array using the dot as the separator.

The first element of the resulting array will always be the string up to the dot (or the whole string if there was no dot in the filename).

Then you can covert the string to lowercase and make the comparison:

```js
function isMakeFile(filename) {
    return filename && filename.split('.')[0].toLowerCase() === 'makefile';
}

console.log(isMakeFile('Makefile')); // true
console.log(isMakeFile('makefile')); // true
console.log(isMakeFile('makefile.ext')); // true
console.log(isMakeFile('makefile.abc')); // true
```

Comment: but why we need to convert in lowercase without lowercase it's working fine based on @Drew answer.

Comment: In that solution, which uses regexp, the pattern is case insensitive (the "i" after the last forward slash). In my solution the equivalent is to convert the case to lower (or upper) and then compare with lower (or upper) of the string we want to find.

Comment: Yes, will add a bit of explanation to my answer to alleviate any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Simple regex to test if a string starts with specified "makefile" prefix.

Searches for matches of a string that start and end exactly with "makefile" **OR** starts with "makefile." and ignores all after the period. The `i` after the pattern is a flag that indicates it is a case-*insensitive* search, meaning upper and lowercase, and any mix between, characters can match.

```
/(^makefile$|^makefile\.)/i.test(filename);
```

```js
const isMakefile = filename => /(^makefile$|^makefile\.)/i.test(filename);

const filenames = [
  "Makefile",     // true
  "makefile",     // true
  "makefile.ext", // true
  "makefile.abc", // true
  "nakeFile.abc", // false
  "makefil",      // false
  "makefiles",    // false
  "makefiles.abc" // false
];

filenames.forEach(filename => console.log(filename, isMakefile(filename)));
```

[image: Edit spring-sea-u4fmq]

Comment: Although unlikely in a real world scenario, this could give false positives. For instance "Makefiles" would also return true.

Answer (score 1):

Why don`t you simply use this one?

```
var n = str.toLowerCase().startsWith("makefile")
if(n===true){
//write your code
}
```

Comment: Do we know if it should match `makefilet de boeuf`?

Comment: but this  method is case sensitive so 'Makefile' not detect .

Comment: Then use toUpperCase() or toLowerCase() to solve this

Ex: someString.toUpperCase().startsWith(someOtherString.toUpperCase())

Answer (score 1):

This will work. Put the file name to the constant **fileName**

```
const fileName = "The file name to test";
return fileName.startsWith("Makefile.");
```